# How to redirect to another page using jquery and node.js express?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I wanna redirect to another page when I clicked a button. I am using node.js express. I want the routers to render the file to the client.
The client code is :

```
var socket = io.connect('/');
$(document).ready(function() {
  socket.emit('createNewUser');
  $('#signup-btn').click(function() {
    var user_info = {
      name: $('#inputUserName').val(),
      email: $('#inputEmail').val(),
      password: $('#inputPassword').val()
    }
     socket.emit('createNewUser', user_info);
     //redirect to '/personal' here
  });
});
```

The routes->index.js code is

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var router = express.Router();


// router.get('/', function(req, res) {
//    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname) + '/views/homepage.ejs');
// });
// router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
//   res.render('homepage', { title: 'Express' });
// });
// router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
//   res.render('signup', { title: 'Express' });
// });
router.get('/personal', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('personal', { title: 'Express' });
});
// router.get('/myFile', function(req, res, next) {
//   res.render('myFile', { title: 'Express' });
// });
// router.get('/updateData', function(req, res, next) {
//   res.render('updateData', { title: 'Express' });
// });
module.exports = router;
```

I have tried several method.
window.location.href=""; does not work.
I used $.get(/personal), it seems that the router can get the request but did not render anything.

Comment: `window.location.href = '/personal'`

Comment: Does not work how exactly? Does it not redirect the browser ?

Comment: I was using <button> for this problem. And the window.location.href gives nothing. Nothing happened. Then I changed the tag to be <a>. And it works fine. Thank you.